# How do I catch an InterruptedException in a thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

Ok, in one of my classes i want to throw an InterruptedException. I do that by calling

```
thread.interrupt();
```

As far as I know this will throw an InterruptedException. What I would like to know is how I can catch this exception in my thread. This obviously won't work:

```
public void run() throws InterruptedException // This results in an error
```

EDIT: If i use a try/catch block in my thread, how can I catch an interruptedexception if I never declare it to be thrown?

Comment: Are you familiar with `try`/`catch` statements?

Comment: Surround with try and catch

Comment: yes I am. however, how should i catch an exception that is never declared to be thrown?

Comment: `try {  code } catch (RuntimeException ex) { do something with ex }` or even just `try { code } catch (Throwable t) { do something with t }` if you want to really go at it.  Just make sure you do something with `ex` or `t` when you've caught it; at least `ex.printStackTrace()` or `t.printStackTrace()` if you need to; with `InterruptedException` though, it's expected to be thrown and used as an indicator.  Read up on Threads.

Comment: @user1420042 you can throw the exception again by chaining the exception, but yor method will need to declare 'throws InteruptedException' and you will need to deal with the exception at some point.

Comment: -1 Read up on threading and how they are interrupted. What you describe is not an interesting thing to do in this way.

Comment: @LeeMeador I was referring to the second code block in his question and explains what it does.

Answer (score 4):

Calling `thread.interrupt` does not automatically throw an `InterruptedException`. You need to regularly check for the interrupt state. Eg:

```
if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    throw new InterruptedException(); // or handle here.
}
```

Some methods do this for you, like `Thread.sleep`, but otherwise no exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your direct question, you would catch it just like any other Exception. Typically, this will be done in response to a sleep command, which does throw the exception. If you catch it, there is no need to throw it beyond the run statement. This should work, for instance:

```
void run()
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex)
    {
        //Do stuff here
    }
}
```

However, I suspect that [InterruptedException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) probably doesn't mean what you think it does. It is only  thrown in a method such as Thread.sleep(), and has nothing to do with `thread.interrupt()`, despite the similar name. If you want to test for a thread.interrupt() coming from a different thread, you need to do something like this:

```
public void run()
{
  while (true)
  {
    if (Thread.interrupted())  // Clears interrupted status!
    {
        //Stop
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

The given code will run a thread forever, until it is interrupted (by another thread calling `interrupt()` on it), where it will stop. Feel free to come up with a more complex example.

Comment: `InterruptedException` is _not_ a `RuntimeException`.  You always have to catch it if it is thrown.

Comment: It is also _not_ "thrown by an external thread".  A thread is interrupted which cause certain methods to throw `InterruptedException `.

Comment: And it's not just thrown in `sleep()` statements.  `Object.wait()` can throw it as well as some NIO methods.  Sigh.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Keep going. thread.interrupt usually interrupts some other thread than the one that is running.

Comment: Well, I think I'm done playing with this for now. I leave it up to you all to determine if it's worth anything.